# Android Questions

Tags: android

I have some questions about android, that i would want to clarify to perfect my android basics knowledge. Here they are.

1- Do we need to declare android manifest permission to get user location?

2- Considering android testing aspects, can we only make tests in apllications directly installed on the emulator or in physical device?

3- AsyncTask it's always executed on the UI thread with the exception of the doInBackgroung method that is executed in a parallel thread?

4- Considering software patterns in android apps, which of these affirmations are true?
 . Android platform favors the development of synchrone operations
 . The Observable pattern can be used to get updates about data in a database
 . The annotations in Room or Retrofit libraries, are used to generate code in build time  that will be 
   used for the application to devop 
 . In communications between activities and fragments we sould pass arguments via intent messages

Thank you all, and rest of a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, even 3
2. Yes. There is blackbox testing, when you don't have the code of the app. And direct testing, when you're the owner of the code of the app and have god knowledge of it. In the 2nd case, the app gets installed along with the test code
3. AsyncTask is deprecated, but yes its doInBackground runs on a different thread than the UI Thread. All other methods of AsyncTask run on the UI thread.
  4.

> Android platform favors the development of synchrone operations

- incorrect, UiCode should run on the main thread, long tasks should run in the background thread. All other code depends on your needs.

> ```
> The Observable pattern can be used to get updates about data in a database
> ```

- Yes, very convenient.

> ```
> The annotations in Room or Retrofit libraries, are used to generate code in build time that will be used for the application to
> ```
>
> devop

- I think it is done at compile time and not runtime.

> In communications between activities and fragments we sould pass
>   arguments via intent messages

There are other options.
 You can use, besides the Intent messages:

- External classes that hold your data
- SharedPreferences
- Databases

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :)